# Rails ".pluck" on joined tables with columns of the same name returns one value and then nil

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
Experiment has_many :features 
Feature belongs_to :experiment

Experiment.where("experiments.id=1")
    .joins(:features)
    .pluck("features.id", "experiments.id")
```

I expect this to return the id of each features and the id of the experiment.

```
[
    [1, 1],
    [2, 1],
    [3, 1],
    # ....
]
```

Instead this returns the id of the experiment and then nil

```
[
    [1, nil],
    [1, nil],
    [1, nil],
    # ....
]
```

This is strange in three regards:

- even though it is an inner join and only an Experiment is returned I am able to pluck columns from features (features.name)
- everything is fine until a column name is repeated.
- the last plucked column is reported first, as if the first column is overwritten. Switching the order of pluck switches the returned value.

This seems like a bug but maybe I am doing something wrong. Any tips?

SQL output:

```
SELECT features.id, experiments.id FROM "experiments" INNER JOIN "features" ON "features"."experiment_id" = "experiments"."id" WHERE (experiments.id=1)
```

Note. This is a simplified question pertaining to a query looking like:

```
Experiment.where("experiments.id=1")
    .joins(feature: { child2: { :child3 } })
    .pluck("feature.id, child3.id")
```

Comment: Not sure, try: `Experiment.where(:id=>1).joins(:features).pluck("experiments.id, features.id")`?

Comment: @Surya Rails is tough to answer.. :-) Before answering we need to create model and insert data.. Too much work :-)

Comment: Same output.  Though I learned that a hash is smarter than a string ("id=1") at picking the proper column to search.

Comment: Which rails version are you using?

Comment: Rails version 4.1.1 :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a bit tricky. Since there's an `INNER JOIN` the query produces only one `id` in this instance. You can actually form query the other way around:

```
Feature.joins(:experiment)
       .where(features: { experiment_id: 1 })
       .pluck(:id, :experiment_id)
```

Or:

```
Feature.joins(:experiment)
       .where(experiments: { id: 1 })
       .pluck(:id, :experiment_id)
```

Comment: Dude! What `features: { experiment_id: 1 }` syntax is doing ?

Comment: within `where` the method will look for the table: `features` and will form query like: `features.experiment_id = 1` :)

Comment: I never saw this syntax(new to me).. Where you found it ?

Comment: Look for "**Equality Conditions**" section here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: I would agree but I think this is working slightly differently than you present.  First, putting features.id first will return the feature.id, which doesn't make sense considering the inner join returning only the Experiment. Second I can pull columns out in this manner fine if the column name is different (ex. features.name works fine).

Comment: I should also note this is a simplified example and my query and the plucked values travel through more children .

Comment: See, when you do joins or includes, ActiveRecord creates a query where you can see `AS t0_r0` etc columns for referencing all columns uniquely, but the ActiveRecord completely changes the query when you use `select` and `pluck` and falls back to the conventional join query, and hence you won't have `features.id` as there's just `id` which refers to experiments table and not features and hence it will NULL. I hope I cleared your doubt?

Comment: When you put `features.id` then it considers id column referencing to features table, at least that's the behavior I think it's following.

Comment: what do you mean by "this is a simplified example and my query and the plucked values travel through more children ." ?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I added some clarification to the question text.

Comment: I am not sure what you're looking for now that you have changed the direction of your question. But all I can see is you have `where(id: 1)` which you change to: `where('experiences.id =?',  1).join(..` in the above query as I don't see if joins will make any sort of affect to the existing structure. Also, please make sure you post original or try to convert your original situation in your question, changing the question with regards to what you really want every now and then may not apply to answers posted before. If you think it's a bug then please report it on rails github issues section :)

Comment: I didn't change anything regarding the question. I have made the syntax match to avoid confusion.  The addition at the end was to show the join spanning multiple children and the pluck doing the same.  The core concept is the same and illustrated well by the exemplar question.

Answer (score 4):

After posting to the rails github I found that my specific issue was resolved in the newest rails release (4.1.6).

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17049